# TSQL reduce the amount of data returned by a query to a parametric defined sample

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table containing a large amount of data which is stored on change.

```
tbl_bigOne
----------
timestamp           | var01 | var02 | ...
2016-01-14 15:20:21 |  10.1 | 100.6 | ...
2016-01-14 15:20:26 |  11.2 | 110.3 | ...`
2016-01-14 15:21:27 |  52.1 | 620.1 | ...
2016-01-14 15:35:00 |  13.5 | 230.6 | ...
...
2016-01-15 09:18:01 |  94.4 | 140.0 | ...
2016-01-15 10:01:15 | 105.3 | 188.7 | ...
...
and so on for years of data
```

What I would like to obtain is a query/stored procedure that given two datetime references (date_from and date_to) gives the required selected data.
Now, the query just mentioned is pretty straight forward what I would also like to achieve is to set the maximum number of rows returned per day (if data is available) while doing the average of the values.

Let's give a few examples:

```
date_from: 2016-01-14 00:00:00
date_to:   2016-01-20 23:59:59
max_points:12
```

in this case the time windows is of 7 days and in this one i would like to have a maximum of 12 rows for each days of the 7 day window, giving a max total of  84 rows whilst doing the average from all the grouping done since, the data for each day is now partitioned by 12. 
It is possible to see this partitioning as if every hour worth of data for that specific day is averaged, generating one row of the 12 required for a day.

```
date_from: 2016-01-14 00:00:00
date_to:   2016-01-14 23:59:59
max_points:1440
```

in this case the time window is one day worth and, if available, i would like to have a maximum of 1440 rows (for each day) for the selected period.

In this way the parameter defines the maximum number of rows for each day. The minimum time window is one day nothing below that.

Can something like this be achieved just using TSQL?

Thank you.

edit for taking care of the observations raised by @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: When you say you need 12 rows per day .  on what basis you need to segregate them ?.also for 1440 rows as well

Comment: So if you want 4 records for 2 days and there exist only 3 records for the first day and 100 for the second, the result is to contain the 3 records for the first day plus 4 records arbitrarily chosen for the second day?

Comment: By the way: It is 8 and 2 days, not 7 and 1 in your examples. (And it's always a bad idea to call something "date" when ist actually a datetime.)

Comment: @TheGameiswar maybe I explained myself wrongly. What i mean is that lets say you have 240 rows worth of data for 1 day (10 entries per hour). The result (with for ex. a limit of 24) should be 24 rows and each row should be the average of 10 rows. So bigger is the time window less will be the limit. Regarding the 1440, same logic applies but it is not  as perfect as in the first example where you have the exact separation by "hours".

Answer (score 0):

Use the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` to number the matching rows per day. Then only keep rows up to the given limit. If you want the rows arbitrarily chosen when there exist more than needed, then number the rows in random order using `NEWID()`.

```
select timestmp, var01, var02, var03
from
(
  select 
    mytable.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by convert(date, timestmp) order by newid()) as rn
  from mytable
  where convert(date, timestmp) between @start_date and @end_date
) numbered
where rn <= @limit
order by timestmp;
```

Comment: am I reading this wrong or this "cuts" the data? If i have 200 rows worth of  data for 1 day I would like to have these 200 rows condensed in lets say 20 but each one of the 20 should be the average of 10 of the 200.

Comment: You are reading this correctly. This is how I understood what you were looking for. Sorry that I have been wrong. So the task is even more complicated. That should best be solved in a stored procedure (pipelined function) with old-fashioned loops, I think.